# Can a browser extension view all files in the file system if I allow access to file URLs?

Tags: browser-addons, microsoft-edge

Can a browser extension view the entire file system if I allow it to access file URLs via the toggle in the settings?

I want to use some browser extensions on local HTML pages I make.  To do that in Microsoft Edge, I need to enable "allow access to file URLs" since by default, browser extensions do not work on local files. The situation is similar in Google Chrome.

I am okay with the risk of an extension reading data from those local files but I do not want it to explore my entire file system if the extension included code to do that.

Comment: they will have at least some access to all the files that the user running the browser has access to. if you can't trust the extension to only look at the files you want it to, then you don't want to use that extension.

Comment: @FrankThomas thank you. If you happen to know one, could you point me to documentation that details what happens when you allow a chrome extension access to the file URLs ?

Comment: well, basically its just allowing the extension to process urls containing the file:// protocol specifier: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme . Any danger comes from the result of how that extension uses that capability (what it is written to do). if you allow this setting, expect that any extension, malicious or not, can access any of the files the user running the browser can, if they choose to. if that app has code to search for files and scribble over them, or delete them, or whatever, it won't be prevented from doing so anymore. there's not really much more than that.